# (React & Mobx & Leaflet) await and then are not working as I expected

Tags: reactjs, async-await, mobx

Good evening.

The purpose of this component is to create a map taking data from `observable curentLocation`. `loadInitialLocation()` and `newMap()` in `useEffect()` should only be called once, and `updateMap()` in `autorun()` is called whenever the `obrservable curentLocation` changes.

The issue is: `newMap()` shouldn't be called until `loadInitialLocation()` finishes its job which is to get data from server and load the result into `observable curentLocation`. Now `newMap()` is called when `obrservable curentLocation` is null.

I tried this in the `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadInitialLocation().then(newMap());
  }, []);
```

where `constant loadInitialLocation:() => Promise<void>`. I expected that "`newMap()` will run only when `loadInitialLocation()` is done".

I also tried this in useEffect():

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getCurLoc = async () => {
      await loadInitialLocation();
      newMap();
    }
    getCurLoc();
  }, []);
```

and this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadInitialLocation().then(newMap());
    autorun(() => {
      console.log("autorun here")
      updateMap();
    });
  }, []);
```

the store:

```
@observable currentLocation: ILocation | null = null;
@action loadInitialLocation = async () => {
      try {
        const currentLocation = await agent.Adventure.locationDetails();
        runInAction(() => {
          this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
          console.log("load currentLocation")
        });
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  };
```

the component:

```
const LeafletMap: React.FC = () => {
  var map: L.Map;
  const tilePixelSize = 32;
  const rootStore = useContext(RootStoreContext);
  const { openModal } = rootStore.modalStore;
  const { currentLocation, loadInitialLocation } = rootStore.mapStore;

  useEffect(() => {
    loadInitialLocation().then(newMap());
  }, []);

  autorun(() => {
    console.log("autorun here")
    updateMap();
  });

  const newMap = () => {
    if (currentLocation == null) {
      console.log("null currentLocation");
      return null;
    }
    // code
    // use currentLocation to load the initial map

    console.log("successfully init map");
  };

  const updateMap = () => {
    if (map == undefined) {
      return null;
    }
    console.log("update map");
    // code
  };
  console.log("add to dom");
  return <div id="map"></div>;
};

export default observer(LeafletMap);
```

If I move to any other page and come back to this, the map will be loaded correctly. I think it's because  that the `oberservable currentLocation` is loaded, and hence the newMap() won't reach `if (currentLocation == null)` and return null.

How do I ensure that only runs `newMap()` after `loadInitialLocation()` is done? Am I not using async, await, and then correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use the right way to call `newMap()`

This should be the correct way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadInitialLocation().then(() => newMap());
  }, []);
```

---

By this, we can assure that we can do "then" only when we get an expected result from mobx action.

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadInitialLocation().then((result) => {
      if (result) {
        newMap(result);
      }
    });
  }, [loadInitialLocation])
```